# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing private variables in OpenMP?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, parallel-processing, openmp

When I was parallelising for-loops using OpenMP in Xcode, there seemed to be a memory access error for private variables (large 2D number arrays, around 2000*2000) that were originally declared as global ones, while it didn't cause any problem before parallelisation.

On my MacBook, it seems that arrays of size 500*500 will crush the programme with error code:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ff7bf66c1d8)
```

I'm wondering if someone could help me resolve this.

See the sample codes below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
// const int x_tot_pixel = 1500, y_tot_pixel = 1500; <- this causes crushes

const int x_tot_pixel = 500, y_tot_pixel = 500;
const int tot_pixel = x_tot_pixel * y_tot_pixel;

double testarray[tot_pixel];

void testfun(int pos, double testarray[tot_pixel]){

   for (int j = 1; j<tot_pixel; j++){
       testarray[j] = 0;
   }
   return 0;
 }

int main(){

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(50) private(testarray)
    for (int i = 1; i < tot_pixel; i++){
       testfun(i, testarray);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I imagine the private arrays are being allocated on the stack and causing a stack overflow